# SQL Agent and Running SSIS Across Network Not Working

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, sql-agent

I have a vb script which moves files from one server to another and it works successfully when run manually but when a job is created in SQL Agent to automate the process it doesn't perform the task.  SQL Agent doesn't fail it simply does not perform the move.

I granted local admin rights to the account performing the task and still nothing. I copied the files manually to the local SQL Server but I still get the same outcome when attempting to run the job in SQL Agent.

I also tried using FQDN but it still doesn't perform the process.  Any suggestions?  Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

if you have 32 bit try:

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

For the package to work.  If you do not have Destop folder, create one and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop`  folder for the package to work.